# Binding DataContext Value that affect by other property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have create a class for the Data Context

```
public class Amt
{            
    private double _Amount = 0;
    public double Amount
    {
        get { return _Amount; }
        set { _Amount = value; }
    }   

    private double _RedeemAmount = 0;
    public double RedeemAmount
    {
        get { return _RedeemAmount; }
        set
        {
            _RedeemAmount = value;            
        }
    }

    private double _BalAmount = 0;
    public double BalAmount
    {
        get { return Amount - RedeemAmount; }
    }
}
```

And I have bind it to TextBox at XAML

```
<TextBox Name="txtAmount" Text="{Binding Amount}" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,2"/>
<TextBox Name="txtRedeemAmount" Text="{Binding RedeemAmount,Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,2" TextChanged="TxtRedeemAmount_TextChanged"/>
<TextBox Name="txtBalAmount" Text="{Binding BalAmount}" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,2"/>
```

Then, what I want is when I change the Redeem Amount in TextChanged event, I expect the Balance amount should change too, I have do some research and try some code on it, but it just not working. Did I do this in wrong way? Any other ways to do this better?

```
private void TxtRedeemAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    double amt = 0;
    double.TryParse(txtRedeemAmount.Text, out amt);
    Amt.RedeemAmount = amt;
   }
```

Thanks for the help anyway!!!

Comment: Your object needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and when Amount or RedeemAmount changes then notify that BalAmount also changes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, you need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Whenever a property of the class is changed you should fire the PropertyChanged event.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

public class Amt : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _Amount = 0;
    public double Amount
    {
        get { return _Amount; }
        set 
        { 
            _Amount = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Amount)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(BalAmount)));
        }
    }

    private double _RedeemAmount = 0;
    public double RedeemAmount
    {
        get { return _RedeemAmount; }
        set
        {
            _RedeemAmount = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(RedeemAmount)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(BalAmount)));
        }
    }

    private double _BalAmount = 0;

    public double BalAmount
    {
        get { return Amount - RedeemAmount; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: "*when I change the Redeem Amount ... I expect the Balance amount should change too*" - quite obviously you would also have to fire the PropertyChanged event for BalAmount in the RedeemAmount setter. In a class where the change of one property affects the value of all other properties, it may make sense to fire the PropertyChanged event with an empty PropertyName, to indicate that all properties have changed.